# What does the number in sysctl configuration file denote?

Tags: sysctl

The sysctl utility allows a Linux admin to query and modify kernel parameters in runtime. For example, to change the swappiness of a Linux system to 0, we can:

1. `echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`

Or we can use `sysctl`:

2. `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=0`

To make the value persistent, [Archwiki suggests](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Swap#Swappiness) to write `vm.swappiness=0`  to `/etc/sysctl.d/99-swappiness.conf` file.

For persistent [silent boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Silent_boot#sysctl), Archwiki suggests to write `kernel.printk = 3 3 3 3` to `/etc/sysctl.d/20-quiet-printk.conf`

Similarly I have a `99-sysrq.conf` on my system which works without the number as well.

---

Archwiki has a [sysctl page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sysctl#Configuration) which mentions the importance of the number:

> Note: From version 207 and 21x, **systemd** only applies settings from
>   `/etc/sysctl.d/*.conf` and `/usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf`. 
>   If you had
>   customized `/etc/sysctl.conf`, you need to rename it as
>   `/etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf`. 
>   If you had e.g. `/etc/sysctl.d/foo`, you
>   need to rename it to `/etc/sysctl.d/foo.conf`.

---

What does the number in `99-swappiness.conf` and `20-quiet-printk.conf` denote here?

Comment: Your files “work without the number”? So you have `vm.swappiness=` and `kernel.printk =` (i.e., without the number)? OK, I figured out what you meant, *in spite of* your explanation.  P.S. That page from the Arch Wiki doesn’t “mention the importance of the number”; it only gives *an **example*** of a filename that begins with a number (and another example with a filename that doesn’t begin with a number).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number at the beginning of the name of configuration files is used as an easily readable way to sort them, with the aim of defining the order of precedence among the entries they contain.

From `man 5 sysctl.d`<sup>1</sup> (emphasis mine):

> CONFIGURATION DIRECTORIES AND PRECEDENCE
>
> ...
>
> All configuration files are sorted by their filename in lexicographic order, regardless of which of the directories they reside in. **If multiple files specify the same option, the entry in the file with the lexicographically latest name will take precedence**. It is recommended to prefix all filenames with a two-digit number and a dash, to simplify the ordering of the files.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The man page for `sysctl.d` is shipped as part of the `systemd` package and the quoted text comes from version 244.3 on Arch Linux. The wording differs to some extent, but not significantly (for the purpose of this Q/A), from both the version currently available at The [Linux man-pages project](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysctl.d.5.html#CONFIGURATION_DIRECTORIES_AND_PRECEDENCE) and the version you can find on [freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sysctl.d.html#confd).</sub>

Answer (score 7):

The prefix establishes a natural order the files are read and applied in. In case of conflicting configurations, the settings in `highnumber-something` will reliably override settings of `lownumber-something`.

Answer (score 6):

Commonly, Linux directories suffixed with `.d`, such as `/etc/sysctl.d` or `/etc/yum.repos.d`, contain configuration files, themselves often suffixed with `.conf`. The files in these kinds of directories will be sorted and read in lexicographic order.

In order to get files in a `.d` directory to execute in a desired order, to load some configuration prior to another, then as a convention we prefix the filename with a number to more easily control the order the files are read.

For example, if you had the files:

```
    10-firstFilename.conf
    20-anotherFile.conf
    30-lastfileToRun.conf
```

They will be sorted and read in this order.

The same files without the numerical prefix would be sorted in the order:

```
    anotherFile.conf
    firstFilename.conf
    lastfiletoRun.conf
```

You can see how the numerical prefix helps implement the desired order.